# Google Search Console does ot recognize JSON-LD dynamically added to head in angular app

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, structured-data, json-ld, angular.js

In my Angular(v1) application, I have a directive that on routeChanging event, remove last added JSON-LDs and add JSON-LD of that page to head element.

```
// .. some codes here

angular.element('.removableJsonLd').remove();

// ... some codes here

var html = angular.element('<script class="removableJsonLd" type="application/ld+json">' + JSON.stringify(json, 0, 2) + '</script>');
$timeout(function () {
    angular.element('head').append(html)
    scope.$applyAsync(function () {
        $compile(html)(scope);
    });
}, 200);
```

When I check the Google Structured Data Testing Tool it show me 3 item. You can check data live [**`[HERE]`**](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fboghrat.com%2Fdr%2Fsahardarafshi%2F%25D8%25AF%25DA%25A9%25D8%25AA%25D8%25B1-%25D8%25B3%25D8%25AD%25D8%25B1-%25D8%25AF%25D8%25B1%25D9%2581%25D8%25B4%25DB%258C).
But Google shows me nothing after 3 weeks in my Webmaster Tools.

[image]

Comment: Has Google crawled this page and updated its indexed tags? If Google hasn't updated your page in its search results yet then this could be what has caused it to not report item #3. A way to test this would be to add a slight edit to the Title or meta description. When the Google result for that page includes the edit then you know that Google has crawled it and updated it, and you can check the Webmaster Tools to see if it's including item 3 again.